# How to create an instance of service in component and provide it for child?

Tags: angular

I have a component `app-group-layers` that gets array of specific instances of classes:

```js
@Input() layers: Layer[];
```

Where layers is something like this:

```js
let layers = [new LayerA(), new LayerB()];
```

The component `app-group-layers` has child component that injected a specific service as `Tree`.

How to create a specific `Tree` in parent component `app-group-layers` depends `@Input() layers` and provide it for child tree component?

As example inside `app-group-layers` component:

```js
constructor() {
   this.layers.forEach((layer) => {
      if (layer instance of LayerA) { // create LayerATree(); // provide this as Tree }
      if (layer instance of LayerB) { // create LayerBTree() // provide this as Tree }
   });
}
```

I am more than sure that the problem is of an architectural nature.

Comment: Just to clarify, when a service is provided in a component, it is available for that component and its child components, see doc: https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components

Comment: I know it, but how to provider a specific new LayerATree() or new LayerBTree() based on @Input layer?

Comment: I think better is to create a concrete instancies LayerATree(), LayerBTree() in place where I fill this `let layers = [new LayerA(), new LayerB()];` using LayerA, LayerB as input parameters. It should be a custom fabric method. I bealive

Comment: Is it good idea to pass a service a @Input parameter to component?

Comment: I don't think so, you should use DI in Angular instead, provide services where appropriate and inject them in the component constructors.

Comment: I believe you are right, and the issue's source is the arcitechture. I would still like to try and help you, could you please share some of the services and classes code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the service in the child component and use a factory to return the proper implementation of the TreeSeevice. The factory is just a function that returns an instance of the service and you can put some logic in there to decide if one implementation or another is provided depending on your needs. All implementations of the TreeService have to match the same interface to make it work. See doc: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-factory-providers

EDIT1: Example with service provider in child component using `useClass`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-workbench-provider-useclass

EDIT2: Example with manual creation of services (no Angular DI) using a factory function, not the most elegant solution but it works. It could be improved by using `useFactory`:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-workbench-provider-usefactory

Comment: I know it, but where to create this fabric and how to pass layer @input to fabric to return a cncrete Tree instance? So Tree service will be injected in TreeComponent. Component would not know what is concrete Tree service uses

Comment: The point is to provide the service in the child component, not in the parent. In the child component you know if the component is A or B and can provide one service or another using the providers array in @Component. You can use a factory or even simpler just provide service A for component A or B for component B, as long as they match the same interface. You can give a look to the Angular docs about DI to see all options with examples: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

Comment: Could you share an example for my case, because it is unclear for me

Comment: If you could post a plunker or similarly I could give it a look ;-)

Comment: Sorry I dont get how to solve this on my case when I have to create instance depends @Input

Comment: Probaly this: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-factory-providers, but how to pass @Input to provider factory?

Comment: See EDIT1 in my previous answer

Comment: Thnak you, but I dont need to create a lot of component, I want to resuse one component in loop with different provider

Answer (score 0):

let say you are trying to create a structure something like this i.e. [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)

```
<app-select [formControl]="control">
  <app-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
    {{ option }}
  </app-option>
</app-select>
```

> `app-select.component.html`
>
> ```
> <div class="app-form-field">
>   <ng-content></ng-content>
> </div>
> ```
>
> `app-select.component.ts`
>
> ```
> constructor(public serviceObj: MyService) { }
> ```

> `app-option.component.html`
>
> ```
> <div class="app-option">
>   <ng-content></ng-content>
> </div>
> ```
>
> `app-option.component.ts`
>
> ```
> constructor(private serviceObj: MyService) { }
> ```

i.e. you have `MyService.ts` that needs to create common instance to share same data across parent and child components. Here is how to modify the parent component i.e. `app-select.component.html`

`app-select.component.html`

```
<div class="app-form-field">
   <ng-container serviceObj>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

What is happening in above code snippt. Injecting obj to `ng-container` like `<ng-container serviceObj>`, passes same instance across all child components (headache is handled by angular itself.)